# How to get value of separate array file name "info.js" in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native. I want to get value from array. I defined the javascripts object that contains Data from "info.js". I want to get the values from info.js in a component name "showInfo.js" using card. below is my code attached.

"info.js"

```
export const STUDENTS= [
   {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Tayyab Arshad',
      image: 'images/tayyab.png',
      College: 'Ncba&e',
      Degree: 'BsCS',
      description: 'I am doing Bs Computer Science'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Abdul Wahab',
      image: 'images/abdul.png',
      College: 'Ncba&e',
      Degree: 'BsCS',
      description: 'I am doing Bs Computer Science'
    }
```

"showInfo.js"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Card, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { STUDENTS} from '../shared/info';

class Info extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            info: STUDENTS
        };
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Info'
    };

    render() {
        const renderInfoItem = ({item}) => {

            return (
                    <ListItem
                        title={item.name}
                        subtitle={item.description}
                        hideChevron={true}
                        leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/tayyab.png')}}
                    />            
            );
        }
        return (
              <FlatList 
                data={this.state.info}
                renderItem={renderInfoItem }
              />
        );
    }
}


export default Info
```

I want to get the information from array(info.js) in a react native component "showInfo.js". but my actual code is not working.

Comment: Your `info.js` does not have the closing square bracket at the end of the file: `]`

Comment: oh; i forget to add "]" here,but i added in my project

Comment: Can you explain in your question what output do you have? A white page, an error (in which case, what error?) ecc..

Comment: Blank Screen....

Comment: How about if the problem is that, this component is not even going to be called because of some other issue? Try importing Text and View from react-native and simply return in your `render() { return (<View><Text>Hello There</Text></View>) }` do you see `Hello There?`

Answer (score 1):

did you try `console.log(this.state.info)` in the render method, I think you have the data , but its not listing as an error in `FlatList` or `renderItem`

just try this to ensure it

```
render() {
    console.log("data :",this.state.info);
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the elements you want to render (`FlatList` and `ListItem`):

```
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Card, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
```

Comment: i just update my code but still did not work. still values are not displaying.. suggest any other way to get values?